# Mutations inside forEach for redux reducer (with immer.js)

Tags: javascript, redux, eslint, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I found a way to solve this issue, but it just feels flat out ugly. I have a custom prop `isMultipleValid` if that prop is `true`, I need to iterate over an array of objects and set on each object `isValid:`property to `false`

> *As of note, I'm also using [immerjs](/questions/tagged/immerjs) (auto-included in
>   [reduxjs-toolkit](/questions/tagged/reduxjs-toolkit)), which allows me to directly mutate an immutable object
>   with an assignment*

### What I want to do:

```
const reducer = createReducer({//...}, {
   [someAction.type]: (state, action) => {
      const { questionId, isMultipleValid } = action.payload;
      const question = state.find((q) => q.id === questionId);
      if (question) {
        if (!isMultipleValid) {
           question.questionOptions.forEach((o) => {
              o.isValid = false;
           }
        }
      // ... more code here, but skipped for readability
      }
   }
})
```

This however results in an [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint) error:

> Assignment to property of function parameter 'o'.
>
> ```
> {
>     "resource": "<PATH>/quizEditorReducer.ts",
>     "owner": "eslint",
>     "code": "no-param-reassign",
>     "severity": 8,
>     "message": "Assignment to property of function parameter 'o'.",
>     "source": "eslint",
>     "startLineNumber": 39,
>     "startColumn": 11,
>     "endLineNumber": 39,
>     "endColumn": 12
> }
> ```

### What needs to be done:

Now as ugly as it feels, there's a workaround to simply re-assign the value to a temporary variable like so:

```
const reducer = createReducer({//...}, {
   [someAction.type]: (state, action) => {
      const { questionId, isMultipleValid } = action.payload;
      const question = state.find((q) => q.id === questionId);
      if (question) {
        if (!isMultipleValid) {
           let temp;
           question.questionOptions.forEach((o) => {
              temp = o;
              temp.isValid = false;
           }
        }
      // ... more code here, but skipped for readability
      }
   }
})
```

Now this will work, but just feels flat-out wrong. Is there a way to bypass this?

---

PS: Yes I know I could simply do `/* eslint no-param-reassign: 0 */` for this file, but it still feels like there should be some way to meet the both ends in the middle

Comment: You can be more selective where you disable the lint rule and do `// eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign` for just that line. You're using a library that enables + encourages mutation, but you have a lint rule that discourages it. One of 'em has to win. You can go for an immutable approach and use `.map` instead of `.forEach`, but that would somewhat defeat the purpose of using immer. Disabling the lint rule seems like the way to go.

Comment: I'm not familiar with immer.js at all, but perhaps this would help? `question.questionOptions.map(o => Object.assign(o, {isValid: false}))`